# Test data in variable range for missing information and notify submitter

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and building off of someone else's code, who was newer to VBA than me!  Thanks in advance for any tips and advice you may have.

Since I cannot post the image I will attempt to describe the dataset.  The data is from a userform, with the bulk of the content in a table range A14:M34, with questions in column A, and data in columns B-M.  The first row is a header the user populates identifying the unit inspected. The data below is populated with pull downs with blank, Yes and NO as options, and a few rows with numeric or character strings.

I want to test each cell in a variably sized range for unanswered questions and notify the user if there are any and give them the option to complete the dataset before submitting.

---

```
    Sub new_p()
        Static AbortProc As Boolean
        Dim iRow As Long
        Dim LastColumn As Long
        Dim aCol As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
        Dim InputRange As Range

        Set ws = Worksheets("PreparationData")
        Set WS1 = Worksheets("ColdWeatherPreparation")
        Set InputRange = WS1.Range("B15:M34")

        If AbortProc Then Exit Sub

        'find last column in range
        LastColumn = WS1.Cells(14, 2).End(xlToRight).Column

        'define variable range of columns
        For aCol = 2 To LastColumn
            'check that the circuit row is not blank
            'If Cells(14, aCol) Is Not Nothing Then
                If IsEmpty(InputRange) Then
                Msg = "All fields are not populated. Stop submission to resume editing?"
                Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)
                    'if yes stop process
                    If Ans = vbYes Then
                    AbortProc = True
                    Exit Sub
                    End If
                    'if no run rest of script
                    If Ans = vbNo Then
                    MsgBox "Run without Correcting?"
                    AbortProc = False
                    Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            'End If
        Next
'more code here that seems to be working
End Sub
```

---

You'll see I have commented out a line I think is redundant.  If End(xlToRight) generates the last populated column of the header row then they are not blank, so no need to test.  Nonetheless I keep code I am not using until the final checks are done and it is proven to be completely useless.  The excessive commenting is to help a large group of non-VBA staffers follow and verify my code before implementing.

So the LastColumn definition seems to work, and I use it again later.  When I step through the code it cycles through the correct number of times for my bogus dataset.  I feel like the isEmpty is where I am falling down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every cell in B15:M34 should be non-blank, then you can do this:

```
If Application.CountBlank(InputRange)>0 Then
    If Msgbox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        'rest of your code
    End If
End If
```

EDIT: this will check each data cell against the corresponding header cell.

```
Sub new_p()
    Static AbortProc As Boolean
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim aCol As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim InputRange As Range, rw As Range
    Dim HeaderRange As Range
    Dim x As Long, Msg As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("PreparationData")
    Set WS1 = Worksheets("ColdWeatherPreparation")
    Set HeaderRange = WS1.Range("B14:M14")
    Set InputRange = WS1.Range("B15:M34")

    'are you sure about this next line?
    'once validation has failed once how does it re-run?
    If AbortProc Then Exit Sub

    For Each rw In InputRange.Rows

        For x = 1 To rw.Cells.Count
            If Len(rw.Cells(x).Value) = 0 And _
               Len(Headerange.Cells(x).Value) > 0 Then

                Msg = "All fields are not populated. Stop submission" & _
                       " to resume editing?"

                If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                    AbortProc = True
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    MsgBox "Run without Correcting?"
                    AbortProc = False
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next x

    Next rw

    'more code here that seems to be working
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not quite every cell.  It's every cell in the inputrange with the column heading populated.  So a variable width range ending at column LastColumn.  And will CountBlank find cells without a selection from a dropdown? The Excel function does count them (just tested).

Comment: And thank you for your quick reply Tim.  I'm thinking I can define a new range using relative references and the LastColumn and use Application.CountBlank you mentioned.

Comment: Would all the column headings be continuous?  ie. might there be any gaps in the headers?

Comment: Doubtful, but possible.  Should be contiguous unless someone decides to get *creative* with their data.

Comment: I'm not sure how to call the **LastColumn** find line (above) in Range syntax. That would do the job right?

Comment: See my edit - a longer way of doing it but more robust.  I'm not sure what the purpose of the Static variable `AbortProc` is? Once you've found some blank cells it will prevent the sub from running again...

Comment: Ideally if there are blanks the individual will want to stop the process and populate them.  Then start over from the beginning.  Since the data is copied to another location then cleared we definitely want to stop the process if they want to edit.  Would you recommend another way to do this?

Comment: I think it was my crazy redundant abortproc. So I commented out all ref to that.  Then the Len line steps through fin.  But it stays in the first column of the InputRange. I need to cycle through the InputRange until a blank is found, or to the LastColumn of data.

Comment: It loops through each cell on each row of `InputRange`: if the cell has no content and the corresponding header cell has a value, then it will flag as "missing data". I'm not sure why you're not seeing that behavior: worked as expected for me...

Answer (score 0):

Errors at Len line? Maybe, because Cells has 2 parameters? `Cells(RowIndex,ColumnIndex)`.

Also, you can set LastColumn by:

```
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

same thing can be done for rows:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Maybe you should move `If AbortProc Then Exit Sub` inside For loop (as first/last line)

Comment: Thank you Pawel.  I pulled the AbortProc.